# Good DB requirements

Tags: mysql

I am currently doing a research project, and I was given with about 400G of data. They are all  pairs, and currently I am using mysql's load data into my db. I have looked into quite a lot of options into mysql's optimization for insertion, but it's taking far too long to complete (estimation is 118 days).

And then I looked into the best key,value store around: Tokyo Cabinet. I absolutely love it, it's fast it's light and it's simple. However, it doesn't allow identical keys to occur more than once. This DOES NOT fit my requirement.

( My data is something like
<1, 2>
<1, 3> 
<1, 4>
<2, 9> ...etc )

Anyone here have something good to recommend? Preferably I want something that has an API for php (cause I will be using a web dev for my internal UI)

Something faster than mysql preferably 
(The only queries I will run is "SELECT c1 from table WHERE c2=X" or "SELECT c2 FROM table WHERE c1=X")

I have to insert all the data once in order to allow the selects to work. So insertion cannot take more than a week on my size of data.

(Distributed is ok, I have a cluster).

Comment: What is the range and domain of your data?  Why precisely have you decided to insert the data into a MySQL database?

Comment: All i am doing is inserting:
<1, 2>
<2, 3>
<1, 3> 
like this. there is only one table with two columns with the primary key being (c1, c2) and another key (c2, c1) for retreival purposes

Answer (score 1):

Have you used [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) before? It's the fastest way to load data in MySQL. 118 days for 400GB sounds like you're iterating through doing a bunch of `INSERT` statements for every row...

Comment: I am using LOAD DATA IN FILE now

Comment: Ok I modified the sourcecode for mysql and recompiled my optimized version. Now it's still taking at least 18 days. 

Any good dbs to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah 400 gigs of data is going to make MySQL beg for mercy. You should be using Oracle or Microsoft SQL.

Even then, once you get this data into a DB what do you plan to do with it? Each query is going to take several minutes.

Comment: Well you see this is not commercial thing. Several minutes for a query is tolerable.